# Can servlet also act as a SOAP WS client?

Tags: servlets, soap, webservice-client

I have done some simple servlets in the past but no SOAP WS clients. Is it possbile for servlets to be WS clients (maybe using JAX, i see that there are some good tutorials on the web)?
I need to get some data from webservice (SOAP) and then offer this data to mobile phones (that's why i chose servlets to respond to HTTP requests).
I alredy have Tomcat server installed and configured and plan to use it.

I know this is a rookie question, but i don't want to start digging in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create servlets that will act as soap clients.
Also worth checking out the [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) project if you want to go the nice Rest route.  So much more relaxing. :)

Comment: Tnx for the tip to go REST route, but unfortunatelly server uses SOAP so i will have to make SOAP client.